# freopen: reverting back to original stream

Tags: c++, c, stdio

I needed to forward stdout to different files to separate some prints produced and the reverting back to normal stdout.

I used `freopen` to switch to the file in this way:

```
char name[80];
memset(name, 0, 80);
strcpy(name, "./scripts/asm/");
strcat(name, m_func->m_name->m_value);
strcat(name, ".shasm");
freopen(name, "w", stdout);
```

And it actually works, but at the end of the process (mind that stdout is redirected many times in the previous same way) I'm not able to revert it to original stdout. I tried the following:

```
freopen("/dev/stdout", "w", stdout);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.. just for information I'm developing on macosx.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to add some more detail, what happens when you do the final freopen()? Does it return NULL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved using fileno, dup and dup2 calls. I have tried this on linux not sure whether this will work on mac but I am sure you will get some equivalent functions for your setup. See if this sample code works for you. Sorry for lack of error-handling in the code. :)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {
        int    fd;
        fpos_t pos;

        printf("stdout, ");

        fflush(stdout);
        fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
        fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
        freopen("stdout.out", "w", stdout);

        f();

        fflush(stdout);
        dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
        close(fd);
        clearerr(stdout);
        fsetpos(stdout, &pos);        /* for C9X */

        printf("stdout again\n");
    }

    f()
    {
    printf("stdout in f()");
    }
```

Comment: Modifying this to #include <errno.h> and then check the return values on the fgetpos/fsetpos calls shows problems on Linux:

if (fgetpos(stdout, &pos)) perror("fgetpos");

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a roundabout way of solving your problem.  Why not just open each file with `fopen()` and then writing to its `FILE *` with `fputs`, `fprintf`, `fwrite` etc?  No need to redirect stdout.

Comment: Probably because a (lot of) code is writing without specifying an output stream, e.g. using just plain printf() calls. Redirecting stdout is then a way of "wrapping" that code and making it write to the desired place, without changing it. Just guessing, of course.

Comment: @unwind your guess is correct, this is the most likely usecase of freopen.

Comment: I can actually confirm that this is the reason. It is a compiler and I always used printf to print asm code (eg. MOV $1, 4.5f) while creating it and now I don't want to waste time replacing things..

Comment: A simple `sed` or `perl` script to do all the replacements and fix the broken code would be a lot better than these ugly hacks.