# Unix C dup2 Question

Tags: c, unix

I have a question regarding `dup2()`. What does it exactly do? Copies the File Descriptor?

I don't quite understand the use of `dup2()`. I tried Google, and still don't quite understand what it means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720535/practical-examples-use-dup-or-dup2 Similar question.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for spotting dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes two parameters that are descriptors.  It makes the second one equivalent to the first one.  You can use them interchangeably with a few minor exceptions... see the man page for more details on the use cases.

You would do this, for example, to redirect the console descriptors 1, 2, or 3, to some other device or file.  The reason you don't want to close those then reopen, is that there is no guarantee you will receive the same number descriptor back in the next open call.  That is why you would use open() to get a file descriptor, then `dup2(new_descriptor, 1);` to force descriptor 1 to go somewhere other than the console.