# What do the dup() and dup2() systems really do?

Tags: c, unix

What do the `dup()` and `dup2()` system calls really do?  How would I use them in practice?

Comment: What part don't you understand after reading the man pages and searching?

Comment: i was unable to understand how to use in programming and where to use

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720535/practical-examples-use-dup-or-dup2 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918962/unix-c-dup2-question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both make a new file descriptor corresponding to an existing open file description. Most properties between the old and new fd (like position) are shared; the only property I can think of that's not shared is the close-on-exec flag. The difference between `dup` and `dup2` is that `dup` assigns the lowest available file descriptor number, while `dup2` lets you choose the file descriptor number that will be assigned and atomically closes and replaces it if it's already taken.

Comment: Also note that `fcntl` with the `F_DUPFD` command behaves similarly to `dup2`, but does not clobber an existing fd, so it can safely be used in threaded programs when trying to create a particular fd number that's not already taken.

Comment: Besides, if the file referenced by `newfd` is already open, it will be closed before the duplication is performed.

Comment: @snr: Not "before". Rather *atomically with respect to*.