# stdin to parent process blocked when calling execv

Tags: c++, fork, stdin, execv

I have created an application that launches a couple of child processes using `fork` and `execv`.

```
string process;  //initialized before execv call
char** process_args;  //initialized before execv call
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    execv(process.c_str(), process_args);
}
```

The processes launch, but they block the parent's access to `STDIN` until every child exits.  I would like the parent process to have access to `STDIN` while the child processes are still running.

Is this possible, and if so - how?  I don't have to use `execv`.  The processes don't really need to have any notion of each other once they are launched.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1720535/1250303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the child's `STDIN` before `exec*()`.

Comment: I tried only closing `STDIN`, but found that I had to close all the streams (`IN`, `OUT` and `ERR`) in order for the console of the parent not to be blocked.  Any idea why this is?  Also, when the parent process is closed now, the child process is not killed, but it was before.  Why does that happen?  Thanks!