# dup2 / dup - Why would I need to duplicate a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I'm trying to understand the use of `dup2` and `dup`.

From the man page:

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> `dup` and `dup2` create a copy of the file descriptor `oldfd`. After successful return of `dup` or `dup2`, the old and new descriptors may be used interchangeably. They share locks, file position pointers and flags; for example, if the file position is modified by using `lseek` on one of the descriptors, the position is also changed for the other.
>
> The two descriptors do not share the close-on-exec flag, however. `dup` uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.
>
> `dup2` makes `newfd` be the copy of `oldfd`, closing `newfd` first if necessary.
>
> #### RETURN VALUE
>
> `dup` and `dup2` return the new descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred (in which case, `errno` is set appropriately).

Why would I need that system call? What is the use of duplicating the file descriptor? If I have the file descriptor, why would I want to make a copy of it? I'd appreciate it if you could explain and give me an example where `dup2` / `dup` is needed.

Comment: How would you implement the piping functionality of shells without `dup` or `dup2` ? You need to call `pipe(2)` and then to have one of the file descriptors `dup`-ed to e.g. `STDIN_FILENO`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [practical examples use dup or dup2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720535/practical-examples-use-dup-or-dup2)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The dup system call duplicates an existing file descriptor, returning a new one that
refers to the same underlying I/O object.

Dup allows shells to implement commands like this:

```
ls existing-file non-existing-file > tmp1  2>&1
```

The 2>&1 tells the shell to give the command a file descriptor 2 that is a duplicate of descriptor 1. (i.e stderr & stdout point to same fd).
Now the error message for calling *ls* on *non-existing file* and the correct output of *ls* on *existing file* show up in *tmp1* file.

The following example code runs the program wc with standard input connected
to the read end of a pipe.

```
int p[2];
char *argv[2];
argv[0] = "wc";
argv[1] = 0;
pipe(p);
if(fork() == 0) {
    close(STDIN); //CHILD CLOSING stdin
    dup(p[STDIN]); // copies the fd of read end of pipe into its fd i.e 0 (STDIN)
    close(p[STDIN]);
    close(p[STDOUT]);
    exec("/bin/wc", argv);
} else {
    write(p[STDOUT], "hello world\n", 12);
    close(p[STDIN]);
    close(p[STDOUT]);
}
```

The child dups the read end onto file descriptor 0, closes the file de
scriptors in p, and execs wc. When wc reads from its standard input, it reads from the
pipe.
This is how pipes are implemented using dup, well that one use of dup now you use pipe to build something else, that's the beauty of system calls,you build one thing after another using tools which are already there , these tool were inturn built using something else so on ..
At the end system calls are the most basic tools you get in kernel

Cheers :)

Comment: So`dup` is helpful for the caller and not the `ls` program itself? Is there any benefit of having `dup` used in program like ls itself if already has access to the file? Here for example, `ls` writes errors to `2` which is is hardcoded, so I have a way to over-ride it as a consumer of `ls`. I think thats a subtle point no?

Comment: Your example program *seems* to have a bug; you're calling `dup(p[STDIN])` but then throwing away the result. Did you mean to use `dup2(p[STDIN], 0)`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone `dup` returns the "lowest numbered descriptor currently not in use by the process." Since fd 0 was just closed, `dup` should return 0. `dup2` is explicit about which fd should be used, instead of just using the lowest free fd, so I would prefer that.

Comment: @Wodin: Ah, I bet you're right about what OP was thinking. Am I also right, though, that "just closed" is relative, and OP's code could break in the presence of, for example, concurrent threads that might be opening files too?

Comment: @Quuxplusone I suspect you're right, but don't know for sure. But in that case you'll have other problems. If you close stdin because you want to read from somewhere else and then another thread opens a file before you do, it will get fd 0. If you then use dup2, it will close the fd that the other thread opened, so the other thread will now be reading from (and writing to?) the file you open. Anyway, if I remember correctly you shouldn't call `exec*` from a multithreaded process. But I am no threading expert :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone or maybe it was `fork` I was thinking of: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: @Wodin JFI: with `dup2` you would not call `close` before.

Answer (score 20):

Another reason for duplicating a file descriptor is using it with `fdopen`. `fclose` closes the file descriptor that was passed to `fdopen`, so if you don't want the original file descriptor to be closed, you have to duplicate it with `dup` first.

Comment: `fdopen()` seems don't duplicate a file descriptor, it just create buffer in user space.

Comment: You misread my answer. The point is that you may want to `dup` the fd before passing it to `fdopen` since `fclose` will close it.

Comment: Why would you call `fclose` if you don't want the file descriptor to be closed? Are you talking about just in the case of like a library function you don't control that calls `fclose`, and you would call `dup` before calling the library function to keep it open?

Comment: @theferrit32: If you allocate a `FILE` handle to access a preexisting open file via stdio interfaces, you need to call `fclose` to deallocate that `FILE` handle. If you want to keep using the underlying open file, or if your software architecture is such that the original "owner" code for the file descriptor will `close` it, the fact that `fclose` also closes the underlying file descriptor you handed to `fdopen` is a problem. You can avoid this problem by using `dup` to make a new file descriptor for the same open file to pass to `fdopen`, so that `fclose` does not close the original one.

Comment: The point is that fdopen() *moves* ownership of the fd to the `FILE`, rather than *copying* it.  That's something users should be aware of.  Consumers that need to retain a usable `fd` handle in addition to the `FILE` object must duplicate the `fd`.  That's all.

Comment: @ConradMeyer: Yes, that's a very good way of putting it, with a note that there is no operation to "move ownership" away from the `FILE` once you move ownership to it.

Answer (score 4):

dup is used to be able to redirect the output from a process.

For example, if you want to save the output from a process, you duplicate the output (fd=1), you redirect the duplicated fd to a file, then fork and execute the process, and when the process finishes, you redirect again the saved fd to output.

Answer (score 4):

Some points related to dup/dup2 can be noted please

dup/dup2 - Technically the purpose is to share one File table Entry inside a **single process** by different handles. ( If we are forking the descriptor is duplicated by default in the child process and the file table entry is also shared).

That means we can have more than one file descriptor having *possibly different attributes* for one single open file table entry using dup/dup2 function.

(Though seems currently only FD_CLOEXEC flag is the only attribute for a file descriptor).

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptor-Flags.html

```
dup(fd) is equivalent to fcntl(fd, F_DUPFD, 0);

dup2(fildes, fildes2); is equivalent to 

   close(fildes2);
   fcntl(fildes, F_DUPFD, fildes2);
```

Differences are (for the last)- Apart from some errno value beteen dup2 and fcntl 
close followed by fcntl may raise race conditions since two function calls are involved.

Details can be checked from 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html

**An Example of use** -

One interesting example while  implementing job control in a shell,  where the use of  dup/dup2 can be seen ..in the link below

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html#Launching-Jobs