# Python: concurrent file seek

Tags: python, concurrency

I am looking at a way to allow concurrent file object seeking.

As a test case of file seeking going wary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import time, random, os
s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

# create some file, just for testing
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()

# the actual code...
f = open('file.txt', 'rb')
def fn():
    out = ''
    for i in xrange(10):
        k = random.randint(0, len(s)-1)
        f.seek(k)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4)/10.)
        out += s[k] + ' ' + f.read(1) + '\n'
    return out

import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
n = 3
res = [p.apply_async(fn) for _ in xrange(n)]
for r in res:
    print r.get()
f.close()
```

I have worker processes, which do random seeking within the file, then `sleep`, then `read`. I compare what they `read` to the actual string character. I do not print right away to avoid concurrency issues with printing.

You can see that when `n=1`, it all goes well, but everything goes astray when `n>1` due to concurrency in the file descriptor.

I have tried to duplicate the file descriptor within `fn()`:

```
def fn():
    fd = os.dup(f)
    f2 = os.fdopen(fd)
```

And then I use `f2`. But it does not seem to help.

How can I do seeking concurrently, i.e. from multiple processes? (In this case, I could just `open` the file within `fn()`, but this is a MWE. In my actual case, it is harder to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot - Python I/O builds on C's I/O, and there is only one "current file position" per open file in C.  That's inherently shared.

What you can do is perform your seek+read under protection of an interprocess lock.

Like define:

```
def process_init(lock):
    global seek_lock
    seek_lock = lock
```

and in the main process add this to the `Pool` constructor:

```
initializer=process_init, initargs=(multiprocessing.Lock(),)
```

Then whenever you want to seek and read, do it under the protection of that lock:

```
with seek_lock:
     f.seek(k)
     char = f.read(1)
```

As with any lock, you want to do as little as logically necessary while it's held.  It won't allow concurrent seeking, but it will prevent seeks in one process from interfering with the seeks in other processes.

It would, of course, be better to open the file in each process, so that each process has its own notion of file position - but you already said you can't.  Rethink that ;-)

Comment: Ah - I see from the [C `dup()` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)... "They refer to the same open file description and thus share file offset and file status flags"

Comment: Not good for multiprocessing ;-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635219/dup2-dup-why-would-i-need-to-duplicate-a-file-descriptor

Comment: Okay, I remember using `dup2()` in college when building a shell, and I guess I have used `dup()` as well. It seems mostly used as a kind of reference counting system to avoid the actual file channel being closed.