# What is the practical use of F_DUPFD in fcntl function

Tags: unix, fcntl

int *fcntl*(int *fd*,F_DUPFD,.../**int arg**/).

The fcntl function in unix programming uses F_DUPFD file descriptor flag.The f_DUPFD clears the FD_CLOEXEC file descriptor for the next lowest available file descriptor. This new file descriptor has the same file table entry as that of *fd*.

What I need is a practical exxample of the implementation of int *fcntl*(int *fd*,F_DUPFD,.../**int arg**/) with proper explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dup2 / dup - why would I need to duplicate a file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635219/dup2-dup-why-would-i-need-to-duplicate-a-file-descriptor)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720535/practical-examples-use-dup-or-dup2