# switch between writing to file and stdout

Tags: c, cross-platform, printf, stdout, iostream

I want to switch between writing to the file and to the `stdout`
I can't use `fprintf`, but only `printf` and `freopen`
something like this:

```
for(size_t i;i<100;++i)
{
     if(i%2)
     {
        freopen("tmp","w",stdout);
        printf("%d\n",i);
     }
     else
     {
        //return to write to stdout?
        printf("%d\n",i);
     }
}
```

How can I return to writing to the `stdout`?

***Update***

I write cross-platform application and  `dup` can't be used.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673764/freopen-reverting-back-to-original-stream.

Comment: @Yakov, answer the first question then.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Why does it really matter this constraint can't be solved as it integral part of my system that all that I can say.

Comment: @Yakov, because it is weird, we want to know why to be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `freopen`. It cannot achieve what you want, and it's a very dangerous function. If it fails, the only safe thing you can do is immediately terminate the program or ensure that `stdout` is never accessed again.

There is a way to do what you want on POSIX systems with `dup` and `dup2`. It looks something like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
int old_stdout = dup(1);
int new_stdout = open("whatever", O_WRDONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
dup2(new_stdout, 1);
close(new_stdout);
/* use new stdout here */
fflush(stdout);
dup2(old_stdout, 1);
close(old_stdout);
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're basing your dire warnings against `freopen` on. got any references? also, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freopen.html says `freopen` is commonly used to reattach `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to other files.

Comment: See this text in the link you provided: "The original stream shall be closed regardless of whether the subsequent open succeeds." Thus, `stdout` is closed if opening the new file fails, and since it's been closed, any function that uses `stdout` (e.g. `printf`) now uses an invalid `FILE *` and thus invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think there's anything stopping you from reassigning these, so you can still handle this gracefully.

Comment: Assigning to `stdout` is not allowed. In fact glibc is just about the **only** system that allows it, and while they allow it explicitly in the documentation, assignments to `stdout` are not actually honored by all internal functions (some of them fail to see it due to symbol visibility or copy relocation related bugs...). Per the standards, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are macros that expand to expressions of type `FILE *`. There is no reason to expect they should even be lvalues, much less modifiable.

Comment: Right. I'd temper the warning slightly though, since it should be safe to use `freopen` at program initialization time, where closing one of the standard handles could be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `dup` the file descriptors, and reopen to the open descriptor. Why can't you use `fprintf`? (Is this homework?)