# Redirect native DLL stdout/stderr from managed wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, redirect, console, pinvoke

I have a `C#` Console app that `P/Invoke`s into a native `C++` dll. The dll creates some threads which are very chatty and write their logs into standard outputs. The problem is that I need Console for my user interactions.

How can I redirect the dll stdout/stderr to `null`?

Comment: Could you change your code so that it makes the calls to the C++ DLL in a separate process?  If so you could launch the separate process with the `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` option.  It may not be exactly what your are looking for, but it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I think than, in order to make this work you will need to build a native DLL that links to the same C++ runtime as the troublesome DLL. You'll then need to use `freopen` to redirect the stdout. My source for this code is this answer: [freopen: reverting back to original stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673764/freopen-reverting-back-to-original-stream/1673879#1673879)

The C++ code would look like this:

```
#include <io.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void RedirectStdOutputToNul(int *fd, fpos_t *pos)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fgetpos(stdout, pos);
    *fd = _dup(fileno(stdout));
    freopen("NUL", "w", stdout);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void RestoreStdOutput(int fd, fpos_t pos)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    _dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
    close(fd);
    clearerr(stdout);
    fsetpos(stdout, &pos);      
}
```

You can p/invoke that from your code like this:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void RedirectStdOutputToNul(out int fd, out long pos);

[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void RestoreStdOutput(int fd, long pos);
```

And you might call it like this:

```
int fd;
long pos;

RedirectStdOutputToNul(out fd, out pos);
print("boo");
RestoreStdOutput(fd, pos);
print("yah");
```

All this relies upon the DLL linking to a dynamic MSVC runtime and you being able to write code that links to same.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a little confused by your question, does the C# app invoke the C++, or the other way around?

Either way, my response is the same for both. Pipe the output of the offending thread into /dev/null (a log would be preferable though...)

If you have control over the c++ dll, use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Else:
[Redirecting standard input of console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application)

Pipe's are awesome. I regularly pipe output into null when I don't want to see the output on the terminal, and I don't feel like remembering how to cause a silent run.